# better algorithm for checking 5 in a row/col in a matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

is there a good algorithm for checking whether there are 5 same elements in a row or a column or diagonally given a square matrix, say 6x6?

there is ofcourse the naive algorithm of iterating through every spot and then for each point in the matrix, iterate through that row, col and then the diagonal. I am wondering if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the matrix?

Comment: 6x6............................

Comment: @randomThought just curious, why u need a complicated logic when it can be done as simple as u explained in question.

Comment: because the method i explained is a bit inefficient.It involves going over each cell in a matrix at least 5 times. Plus, python and some other similar languages have stellar list processing capabilities that might make this much easier or simpler

Comment: You should edit your question and mention that this is for Pentago, and explain the 3x3 rotation, because it probably matters a lot for the efficiency of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether there are k same elements in a matrix of integers in a **single pass**.

Suppose that n is the size of the matrix and m is the largest element. We have n column, n row and 1 diagonal.
Foreach column, row or diagonal we have at most n distinct element.

Now we can create a histogram containing (n + n + 1) * (2 * m + 1) element. Representing 
the rows, columns and the diagonal each of them containing at most n  distinct element.

```
size = (n + n + 1) * (2 * m + 1)
histogram = zeros(size, Int)
```

Now the tricky part is how to update this histogram ?

Consider this function in pseudo-code:

```
updateHistogram(i, j, element)

    if (element < 0)
        element = m - element;

    rowIndex        = i * m + element
    columnIndex     = n * m + j * m + element
    diagonalIndex   = 2 * n * m + element

    histogram[rowIndex] = histogram[rowIndex] + 1
    histogram[columnIndex] = histogram[columnIndex] + 1

    if (i = j)
        histogram[diagonalIndex] = histogram[diagonalIndex] + 1
```

Now all you have to do is to iterate throw the histogram and check  whether there is an element > k

Answer (score 3):

You could keep a histogram in a dictionary (mapping element type -> int). And then you iterate over your row or column or diagonal, and increment `histogram[element]`, and either check at the end to see if you have any 5s in the histogram, or if you can allow more than 5 copies, you can just stop once you've reached 5 for any element.

Simple, one-dimensional, example:

```
m = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A']

h = {}
for x in m:
    if x in h:
        h[x] += 1
    else:
        h[x] = 1

print "Histogram:", h

for k in h:
    if h[k]>=5:
        print "%s appears %d times." % (k,h[k])
```

Output:

```
Histogram: {'A': 5, 'B': 1}
A appears 5 times.
```

Essentially, `h[x]` will store the number of times the element `x` appears in the array (in your case, this will be the current row, or column or diagonal). The elements don't have to appear consecutively, but the counts would be reset each time you start considering a new row/column/diagonal.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by a histogram in this context? would it work if there are 5 non consecutive elements? such as AAAABA ?

Comment: I added an example and a bit of an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For rows you can keep a counter, which indicates how many of the same elements in a row you currently have. To do this, iterate through the row and

- if current element matches the previous element, increase the counter by one. If counter is 5, then you have found the 5 elements you wanted.
- if current element doesn't match previous element, set the counter to 1.

The same principle can be applied to columns and diagonals as well. You probably want to use array of counters for columns (one element for each column) and diagonals so you can iterate through the matrix once.

I did the small example for a smaller case, but you can easily change it:

```
n = 3
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
          [1, 2, 3, 1], 
          [2, 3, 1, 3],
          [2, 1, 4, 2]]
col_counter = [1, 1, 1, 1]
for row in range(0, len(matrix)):
    row_counter = 1
    for col in range(0, len(matrix[row])):
        current_element = matrix[row][col]

        # check elements in a same row
        if col > 0:
            previous_element = matrix[row][col - 1]
            if current_element == previous_element:
                row_counter = row_counter + 1
                if row_counter == n:
                    print n, 'in a row at:', row, col - n + 1
            else:
                row_counter = 1

        # check elements in a same column
        if row > 0:
            previous_element = matrix[row - 1][col]
            if current_element == previous_element:
                col_counter[col] = col_counter[col] + 1;
                if col_counter[col] == n:
                    print n, 'in a column at:', row - n + 1, col
            else:
                col_counter[col] = 1
```

I left out diagonals to keep the example short and simple, but for diagonals you can use the same principle as you use on columns. The previous element would be one of the following (depending on the direction of diagonal):

```
matrix[row - 1][col - 1]
matrix[row - 1][col + 1]
```

Note that you will need to make a little bit extra effort in the second case. For example traverse the row in the inner loop from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach may depend on whether you control the placement of elements.

For example, if you were building a game and just placed the most recent element on the grid, you could capture into four strings the vertical, horizontal, and diagonal strips that intersected that point, and use the same algorithm on each strip, tallying each element and evaluating the totals.  The algorithm may be slightly different depending on whether you're counting five contiguous elements out of the six, or allow gaps as long as the total is five.

Comment: the game is the pentago game. i will need to look up the entire board everytime since the player can rotate a part of the board. this would work for other games where the board stays the same.

Comment: So, if you're grabbing the whole board, then you'd do as described above for all possible vertical, horizontal, and diagonal strips (starting from the left edge and having a length >=5).  It's a small array of 18 strings.  If your string consisted of "b", "w", or "." as characters, then an example would be "b..www".  You search for the substring "wwwww" to see if white won or the substring "bbbbb" to see if black won.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid iteration, but you can at least do an XOR of all elements and if the result of that is 0 => they are all equal, then you don't need to do any comparisons.

Comment: Not true, this will only work for checking 2 elements in a row. XOR of an odd number of equal elements will be non-zero. It is possible to have 3 or more non-equal elements where the XOR is 0 (for example 01 XOR 10 XOR 11 in binary).

Comment: My bad, misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try improve your method with some heuristics: use the knowledge of the matrix size to exclude element sequences that do not fit and suspend unnecessary calculation. In case the given vector size is 6, you want to find 5 equal elements, and the first 3 elements are different, further calculation do not have any sense.

This approach can give you a significant advantage, if 5 equal elements in a row happen rarely enough.

Comment: This is a good idea but in a game where people try to get 5 in a row, there are likely to be a lot of rows where the first 2-3 elements are similar since thats what the players are likely to do.

Comment: @randomThought, BTW, if you are writing a game where user can change position of some numbers in a single step, there is no need to recheck the whole game field on each step.

Answer (score 0):

If you code the rows/columns/diagonals as bitmaps, "five in a row" means  "mask % 31== 0 && mask / 31 == power_of_two"

- 00011111 := 0x1f 31 (five in a row)
- 00111110 := 0x3e 62 (five in a row)
- 00111111 := 0x3f 63 (six in a row)

If you want to treat the six-in-a-row case also as as five-in-a-row, the easiest way is probably to:

```
for ( ; !(mask & 1) ; mask >>= 1 ) {;}
return (mask & 0x1f == 0x1f) ? 1 : 0;
```

Maybe the Stanford bit-tweaking department has a better solution or suggestion  that does *not* need looping?